# Orchard cms tracking record repository like tracking content item in Audit Trail

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using Orchard's Audit Trail module to track change content items.
But, in my project, I has some objects that only have record model (don't have part model), I query and save them by using Repository.Fetch()

In Audit Trail module, it override Updating(), Updated() method to track change a content item.

I want to know if there are something like that for record Repository, because I also want to track objects that only use record model.

Ex:

I have these models : InvoicePart, InvoicePartRecord, DetailRecord, ProductPart, ProductPartRecord

An Invoice has many Details.

Detail stores Invoice_Id & Product_Id, salesman can add more Details into Invoice, or delete it from Invoice, or change Product_Id of a Detail.

Orchard Audit Trail can only tracking change for Invoice & Product, but not for Detail because it is not a content item, so that I can not know when a Detail was created, modified or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must add new repository implementation inherited from the original one, like this:

```
public class MyRepository<T> : Repository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class
```

here, you can trigger your events whenever you want to track changes.
Then, to suppress the original implementation you must add new Autofac Module class:

```
public class DataModule : Module {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) {
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

after that you can handle these events and audit them, you will find a good sample on this in Orchard.AuditTrail module with ContentDefinitionProviders.

Note: if you want to specify the records which have auditing enabled (this useful if you don't want to audit all the changes on all records in your system), you can add a new class attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class AuditTrailEnabledAttribute : Attribute {
}
```

then use this attribute to check if the record class has it or not, and do your auditing based on it.

Comment: I can't find ContentDefinitionProviders , and when I save a record while debugging, I see it don't run into any Load() method